# Delete Duplicate Row in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need this script to delete the row (within the Registration sheet) with the matching Registration Code to the Cancel Registration sheet's Registration code. As of now, this script only deletes a row if "sheetR.deleteRow(i);" is not inside "if (regCodeR === regCodeCR) {}". It doesn't delete the correct row either.

```
function rD() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetR = ss.getSheetByName("Registration");
  var sheetCR = ss.getSheetByName("Cancel Registration")
  var dataR = sheetR.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataCR = sheetCR.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headerRow = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i in dataR && i in dataCR; ++i) {
      var rowR = dataR[i];
      var rowCR = dataCR[i];
      var duplicate = false;
      var regCodeR = sheetR.getRange(headerRow + i, 10).getValues();
      var regCodeCR = sheetCR.getRange(headerRow + i, 9).getValues();
          if (rowR[9] === rowCR[8]) {
          duplicate = true;
          }
  }
  if (regCodeR === regCodeCR) {
      sheetR.deleteRow(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code with simple data having one column with registration numbers. You can modify the main sheet range according to your data. Also make sure to change the sheet names.

Tried and tested the code below :

```
function deleteDup(){
  var mainSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('regis');
  var cancelSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('cancel');
  var mainSheetValues = mainSheet.getRange(2, 1, mainSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var cancelSheetValues = cancelSheet.getRange(2, 1, cancelSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var k = 0;
  var del = [];
  // Getting the row index of matching values
  for (i = 0; i < cancelSheetValues.length; i++)
  {
    var cancelValue = cancelSheetValues[i][0];
    Logger.log(cancelValue);
    for (j = 0; j < mainSheetValues.length; j++)
    {
      if(mainSheetValues[j][0] == cancelValue){
        del[k] =  j;
        k++;

      }
    }

  }
  del.sort();
  var count =0;
  // deleting the values from the main sheet values array
  for (i = 0; i < k; i++ )
  {
    mainSheetValues.splice((del[i] - count), 1);
    count++;
  }
  var len = mainSheetValues.length;
  // Update the sheet with new values
  mainSheet.getRange(2, 1, mainSheet.getLastRow(),1).clearContent();
  mainSheet.getRange(2, 1, len,1).setValues(mainSheetValues);

}
```

But instead you can also do this way:

1. Set a flag value in the registration sheet if it matches with the cancellation sheet.
2. Then loop through the registration sheet data and delete the matching flag row.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried your script after changing the sheet names, however it only deletes the cells and actually deletes all of them in the column, not just the ones that match from the other sheet.

Comment: i'm not familiar with setting flag values. Sounds like a good idea. I have searched it and I can't find any examples of how to do it.

Comment: I only tested the above code with simple data(one column with registration values.). Please post the example sheet. May be I can help you.Regarding the Flag, you could just update a cell value to true or false depending on the matching and loop through that column and make changes accordingly.

Comment: I think I did something similar to updating the cell value to true/false, only i had the cell value change to Y (for registered), only it didn't put the Y in the correct row. It placed the Y in the row position where the duplicate was in the Cancel Registration sheet. It was row position dependent and I couldn't figure out a way to change it so that it matched to the right row in the Registration sheet.